# Error adding RDS license to a server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

I have an RDS license for 100 users.

I successfully assigned it to one RDS server without issue, but when I tried it on another server I get an error.

1. Open RD Licensing Manager
2. Right click the server and choose activate- this works fine
3. Right click the now activated server and choose install licenses
4. License Program: License Pack (retail Purchase)
5. Plugin and add my license
6. It tries to install it

On the next page I see this:
[image]

I see no error or warning in event viewer after running this operation.

Same steps and same code I used for the other server and it worked on that one without issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably do some reading on RD Licensing in 2012. [This Technet blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2013/09/20/rd-licensing-configuration-on-windows-server-2012/) has a pretty good explanation.

At a high level, you don't actually install/activate your license on every RDS server. You install the `Remote Desktop Licensing` role service on a server and apply your license there. Then you configure your `RD Session Host` and `RD Virtualization Host` servers to point to that licensing server. It's a similar concept to how KMS based licensing works for the OS.

Comment: So if my licensing server fails users won't be able to connect to the other server? Why would the GUI let you add multiple licensing servers? Do I need a different license for each one?

Comment: If you licensing server fails, you will get a licensing error when someone tries to connect. You can configure multiple licensing servers so if one fails the other still provides licenses when they are requested.

Comment: Yeah I need separate licenses for each licensing server :(